# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (OpenGL with xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

I am very new to using OpenGL. The program I am trying to run is provided by my professor so I have not actually written any of it, I am having problems getting the program to run. The program is suppose to just make a white square on a black screen. I am using mac Sierra 10.12.2. Also I have already changed the deployment target to 10.8 because of the errors from compiling in anything later than that. Now when I try to build and run in xcode I get 2 errors.

These are the errors im getting,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"exit(int)", referenced from:
   myKeyboard(unsigned char, int, int) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now here is the code exactly as I am trying to compile it.

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

const int screenHeight = 480; // window height is 480
const int screenWidth = 640 ; //window width is 640
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Prototypes >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void exit(int) ;
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< myInit >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void myInit(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);       // set white background color
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);          // set the drawing color
    glPointSize(4.0);              // a ?dot? is 4 by 4 pixels
    glLineWidth(4.0);              // a ?dot? is 4 by 4 pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 480.0);
}
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< myDisplay >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     // clear the screen
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    //  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP) ;
    //  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP) ;
    //  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(289, 190);        // Dubhe
    glVertex2i(320,  128) ;        // Merak
    glVertex2i(239,  67) ;        // Phecda
    glVertex2i(194,  101) ;       // Megrez
    glVertex2i(129,  83) ;       // Alioth
    glVertex2i(75,  73) ;       // Mizar
    glVertex2i(74,  74) ;       // Alcor
    glEnd();
    glFlush();          // send all output to display
}
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< myKeyboard >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
void myKeyboard(unsigned char theKey, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    switch(theKey)
    {
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
            exit(-1); //terminate the program
        default:
            break; // do nothing
    }
}
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< main >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
int  main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);          // initialize the toolkit
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); // set display mode
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);     // set window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150); // set window position on screen
    glutCreateWindow("Big Deep - Type Q or q to quit") ; // open the screen window
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);     // register redraw function
    glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard); // register the keyboard action function
    myInit();                   
    glutMainLoop();              // go into a perpetual loop
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm very depressed that professors are still teaching OpenGL like this. You might want to sit down with your professor and remind them that [they should not be teaching Legacy OpenGL](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34108/opengl-vbo-or-glbegin-glend) and should stick to OpenGL functions that were not made deprecated back in 2008. Great quote from the post I linked: "*Some people think learning the old stuff first is better because it's a bit easier, but that stuff you learn is mostly useless and then stuff you have to unlearn.*".

Comment: FYI, the errors you're getting are the result of Linking errors, specifically having to do with your professor's use of `exit`. Somehow, somewhere in your build process, you're not referencing the correct object files to link to your final executable. If I knew anything about your specific build environment, I'd post more detailed diagnosis instructions as an answer.

Comment: His reasoning for wanting to teach 2.x is because "Its better for teaching, and its easier to build up to 4.x rather than learning 4 and then learning the older stuff" which also doesn't really make sense to me either. I'm probably wrong but I think that the exit function is apart of the GLUT library, but i'm not sure honestly. Thats about all I can really offer as help, like I said I just started trying to use this today. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following near the top of your source file:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

and remove this line:

```
void exit(int) ;
```

First, you should always use the proper system headers to get the declarations of system library functions. This is especially true on macOS where the declaration can have important attributes which affect how the function is linked.

However, the lack of such attributes is not really what tripped you up in this case. The issue here is that you're building a C++ program. In C++, a function's argument types are part of its symbol name. You can see this in the error message you've quoted. But the `exit()` function is part of the C standard library. It's not natively a C++ interface. Its symbol name is `_exit`, with no indication of its argument count or types.

Your code has incorporated references to a symbol that translates to `exit(int)` while the actual symbol in the system library is just `_exit`. They don't match, so you get a symbol-not-found linker error.

The stdlib.h header takes special care to wrap its function declarations in `extern "C" { ... }` when it's included for a C++ translation unit. So, including that header to get the declaration tells the C++ compiler not to use a C++-style symbol name but to instead just use the C-style symbol name.

You could also "solve" the issue by putting `extern "C"` on the declaration of `exit()` in your own code, but that's the wrong approach. Just include the proper header.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I changed it and it worked great! So what was weird is that at a point I knew it was something to do with not including the right library. So I just started adding libraries just to see what would make it work and    #include <iostream> made it work. I figured it was because I thought since asking for 'q' or 'Q' to terminate, it needed an input library.